# Как получить доступ к children в функциональном компоненте?

Tags: reactjs

Переписал один class-based компонент на функциональный лад. Ну и получил ошибку в строке, где находится `{this.props.children}`. Нагуглил, что нужно вместо

```
export function MyComponent(props: MyProps) {}
```

Сделать

```
export function MyComponent(props: React.FC<MyProps>) {}
```

Но теперь у меня вообще нет доступа к пропсам. В том числе и к `children`:

> Property 'onRequestClose' does not exist on type 'FunctionComponent'
>
> Property 'children' does not exist on type 'FunctionComponent'

Answer (score 0):

```
<Input>
  I'm Children
</Input>

const Input = ({ children }) => <input type="text" />;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]